# Are there any difference between the two statements?

Tags: php, arrays

```
array_key_exists($name, $defaults)

isset($defaults[$name])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) returns *false* if the value is *null* while [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) doesn’t:

```
$defaults = array('foobar' => null);
var_dump(array_key_exists('foobar', $defaults));  // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($defaults['foobar']));             // bool(false)
```

So you should always use `array_key_exists` for array keys unless you don’t want to make a difference whether an array item exists or is *null*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick comment from the PHP manual talking about the [performance differences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#82867) between the two! <strike>But they do the same thing :-\</strike>

Strike that, I'm an idiot.

Comment: No, they don't do the same thing : `isset` will return `false` when a value is defined, but `null` ; `array_key_exists`, on the other hand, will return `true` ;;; see the note on Example #2 : http://php.net/array_key_exists